# Problems with \begin{enumerate}[1.3.i]

Tags: enumerate

I should have searched more for this subject before posting, I'm sure, but I got frustrated with the amount of interesting items of clothing made from latex, so please forgive me if this has already been answered. I'm trying to make a list of examples like:

> 1.3.i bla bla
>   1.3.ii and so on
>   ...

I feel I should be able to use `\begin{enumerate}[1.3.i]`, but it comes out as:

> i.3.i bla bla
>   ii.3.ii and so on
>   ...

I suppose it makes sense, since '1' is one of the characters that get interpreted, but isn't there a way to protect the number, when you just want it to be a static part of the label?

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newcommand*{\foo}{1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[\foo.i]
\item Lorem
\item Ipsum
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}` could be a dirty work-around. You may also want to look into the `enumitem` package. The question is where the "1.3" comes from, maybe that could be automated (for example if it is the subsection number with `\thesubsection` instead of foo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to hide the fixed part (which contains a `1` that would otherwise be mistaken for a counter denotation):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\setcounter{subsection}{2} % faking two subsections

\subsection{Title}

\begin{enumerate}[{1.3}.i]
\item bla bla
\item and so on
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's easier with `enumitem` that is much recommended over `enumerate`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\setcounter{subsection}{2} % faking two subsections

\subsection{Title}

\begin{enumerate}[label=1.3.\roman*]
\item bla bla
\item and so on
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

However, both solutions suffer from the hardcoded `1.3`; also, the labels will be poorly aligned. Here's my suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\setcounter{subsection}{2} % faking two subsections

\subsection{Title}\label{ssec:xyz}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\ref{ssec:xyz}.\roman*,align=left]
\item bla bla
\item and so on
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Using `\label` and `\ref` will ensure the enumeration will have the correct label, independently on possible changes in the material.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So {1.3} works - I should have thought of that. But I will look into to enumitem, it does look better.

Answer (score 1):

You can 'hide' the `1.3` from `enumerate`'s parser by putting it into a macro

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newcommand*{\enumprefix}{1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[\enumprefix.i]
\item Lorem
\item Ipsum
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the "1.3" is not a random number, but stands in relation with other counters in the document, you may be able to get rid of the `\newcommand`. If it is the number of the current subsection, you would use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
\begin{enumerate}[\thesubsection.i]
\item Lorem
\item Ipsum
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But you could also use the [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package, which has a slightly more verbose syntax here, but offers many additional options. Plus, you can hide the more verbose settings in your own macro definitions or apply the globally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\thesubsection.\roman*]
\item Lorem
\item Ipsum
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```